# How do I list all files ever committed to the repository?

Tags: svn, search, repository, revision

How could I let SVN list all files which were ever committed to a repository (if possible, along with location and revision).

More exactly: I need all ever existed paths.

*If someone knows how to do a fulltext search on the entire repository (including **all** revisions), this would help me even better.*

#### Example

Let's say I commit a file `SomeFileOne.txt`, later rename it to `SomeFileTwo.txt`.

After performing the required task (for which solution I'm looking for), I should get not only `SomeFileTwo.txt`, but also `SomeFileOne.txt`.

```
...
/trunk/SomeProject/SomeFileOne.txt - revision 100
/trunk/SomeProject/SomeFileTwo.txt - revision 101
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, svn log -v would have been a more intuitive method - or have you already tried that ? Is it possible to share the need for requiring such an extensive report on all the file commits ever made in the repository?

Answer (score 3):

Found out something by playing around.

A slow-and-dirty solution might be:

```
svnadmin dump MY_REPO | grep Node-path
```

Output looks like:

```
* Dumped revision 3039.
Node-path: trunk/proj1/src/p/keywords/main/NoOp.java
Node-path: trunk/proj1/src/p/keywords/main/ScopeDecl.java
* Dumped revision 3040.
Node-path: trunk/myCommons/src/i/IConverter.java
Node-path: trunk/myCommons/src/i/ListUtils.java
* Dumped revision 3041.
Node-path: trunk/proj1/src/p/execution/impl/IterativeExecuter.java
Node-path: trunk/proj1/src/p/keywords/DeclConstant.java
```

Well, at least it solves my problem.

*NOTE: `Dumped revision ...` is shown, because it's `stderr`.*

Comment: Oh, stderr and stdout seems not to be synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

For an improved, structured output to svn log -v, use the following bash script:

```
$ svn log -v | egrep '^   A' | cut -c 6- | sort | uniq
```

Explained:

- fetch the whole svn log of the given path
- select only lines starting with '   A', which is the svn log output for an added file.
- cut away the first 5 chars, which is the mentioned add info
- sort the output
- remove duplicate lines (e.g. if a file was readded later)

This also works for subpaths of the checkout, you don't even need a checkout at all, if you provide the repository path:

```
$ svn log -v https://github.com/schacon/kidgloves/ | egrep '^   A' | cut -c 6- | sort | uniq
```

Result:

```
/branches
/branches/testing (from /trunk:17)
/trunk
/trunk/README
/trunk/example.rb
/trunk/kidgloves.rb
/trunk/simple_rack.rb
```

Right, the file list may not be perfect for automated processing yet, but it goes a long way from just the log output, if I may say so. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to browse around you might get what you want with one of the svn web access tools. A roundup was [written up over here.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210115215835/http://geekswithblogs.net/flanakin/articles/CompareSubversionWebTools.aspx)