# How to list all files in a remote SVN repository?

Tags: svn, repository, remote-access

I access a **large** remote SVN repository. Since I usually only need a tiny subset of its content I did a "sparse checkout":

```
svn checkout --depth empty svn+ssh://... src
```

Whenever I need a folder from the repository I can just do

```
svn up folder
```

and when I don't need it anymore I use

```
svn up --set-depth exclude folder
```

But now I need a complete list of **all** the files in the repository and I don't want to do a complete checkout just to get the file and folder names.

I already tried `svn ls -R` which will indeed list some files I didn't check out but still there are some missing. I know because it does show everything in the current directory. Now I could semi-manually execute `svn ls` and `svn up --depth empty` for every new-found directory, but I wonder if there is some better alternative.

In contrast to [How do I list all files ever committed to the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695010/) I'm only interested in the current content of the repository and I do not have access to `svnadmin`. Neither can I install software on the repository server.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This lists all files recursively:

```
svn ls -R URL-OF-REPO
```

Comment: Thanks! Explicitly using the repo URL did the trick. And yes, `-R` can be used.

Comment: FYI...Something that caused me to waste a lot of time is that SVN externals don't show in the output from the above command.  Your directory structure of a working copy on disk won't match the output of 'svn ls' if you have externals. Keep that in mind if you are comparing them somehow as I was.

Answer (score 10):

```
svn list --recursive https://myrespository.my.com/Myproject
```

I think that works for current and all subdirectories as I tried. This one lists all branches and tags as well, and all their subdirectories and files.

Answer (score 7):

You can try my utility [fast-svn-crawler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fastsvncrawler/), it is [much faster](http://vcs.atspace.co.uk/2013/03/16/fast-listing-of-svn-repository-with-svn-crawler/) than "svn list --recursive".

```
$ svn-crawler https://myrespository.my.com/Myproject
```

Comment: Thanks for building this! A quick build note: On CentOS 6 box I had to modify the CMakeLists.txt file to change "include/apr-1.0" to "include/apr-1".

Comment: Awesome tool. Is there a way to include file sizes as well?

Comment: No, file sizes retrieving would require a separate request for each file; that would slow down the utility a lot. It could easily print [additionally] only "last changed revision", "last changed date", and "the author of the last change" (this information is in svn:entry:* properties that are received within the same request).

Answer (score 2):

Without URL

`svn list --recursive -r HEAD`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a complete list of all the files and not the folders, you can pipe *svn list* and *grep* command like this:

```
svn list -R svn://url/to/your/main/folder/on/repo | grep '[^\/]$'
```

the path to folders listed by

> *svn list -R svn://url/to/your/main/folder/on/repo*

always ends with "/" while file path doesn't. The output is passed as an input to

> *grep '[^\/]$'*

which excludes all the paths having a trailing *"/"*; the remaining paths are only related to files.

Example: let's assume we have a repository named *myrepo* on *my.svnserver.com* as a domain, and we want to get all the files listed in a subdirectory of *myrepo* i.e. *mysubdir*: the command is

```
svn list -R svn://my.svnserver.com/myrepo/mysubdir | grep '[^\/]$'
```

Also, if you pipe the result to *wc -l* command (which prints the number of newlines, as each output line contains one path only), you can get the number of all the files under *mysubdir*, like this

```
svn list -R svn://my.svnserver.com/myrepo/mysubdir | grep '[^\/]$' | wc -l
```